# Plotly not rendering correct plot with subset of dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to subset a dataframe and using `plotly` for creating bar chart:

```
resort_pos %>% subset(resort + pos > 5000)%>% 
mutate(pos_percentage = (pos*100)/(resort+pos)) %>% 
mutate(Source = as.factor(src)) %>% 
plot_ly(x= ~Source,y= ~pos_percentage, type = "bar")
```

Below are the head of resort_pos and subset of resort_pos

```
>>head(resort_pos)
src resort positive
1 ABL  45686     7352
2 AGR     96        0
3 AMD  15857    21077
4 BAM   3806   141275
5 BBI    416       54
6 BDQ      5        0

>>head(resort_pos %>% subset(resort + pos > 5000)%>% 
    mutate(pos_percentage = (pos*100)/(resort+pos)) %>% 
    mutate(Source = as.factor(src)))

 src resort positive pos_percentage Source
1 ABL  45686     7352       13.86176    ABL
2 AMD  15857    21077       57.06666    AMD
3 BAM   3806   141275       97.37664    BAM
4 BIL  73847   142660       65.89163    BIL
5 BLR  52711   192061       78.46527    BLR
6 BNO  44069    71089       61.73171    BNO
```

Here's the output:

[image]

`x` takes all the distinct values but since `y` is not available in the subsetted data frame, it shows blanks. How can I circumvent this?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.  I guess you want `resort_pos %>% filter((resort + pos) > 5000) %>%`

Comment: I did store the subset output in a separate dataframe. It has 17 observations while original dataframe has 47. Then used plotly on the subsetted dataframe but issue still exists. I will include head of the dataframes in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `droplevels()` on the resulting data.frame.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks. Strange that plotting using ggplot does not have this probelm.